# Complexity of function with array having even and odds numbers separate

Tags: c++, sorting, time-complexity, insertion-sort, code-complexity

So i have an array which has even and odds numbers in it.
I have to sort it with odd numbers first and then even numbers.
Here is my approach to it:

```
 int key,val;
int odd = 0;
int index = 0;

for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]%2!=0)
    {
        int temp = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
        index++;
        odd++;
    }
}
```

First I separate even and odd numbers then I apply sorting to it.
For sorting I have this code:

```
for (int i=1; i<max;i++)
{
    key=arr[i];
    
    if(i<odd)
    {
       val = 0;
    }
    if(i>=odd)
    {
        val = odd;
    }
    
    for(int j=i; j>val && key < arr[j-1]; j--)
    {
        arr[j] = arr[j-1];
        arr[j-1] = key;
    }
}
```

The problem i am facing is this i cant find the complexity of the above sorting code.
Like insertion sort is applied to first odd numbers.
When they are done I skip that part and start sorting the even numbers.
Here is my approach for sorting if i have sorted array e.g: **3  5  7   9   2   6   10  12**
[complexity table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSXpq.png)

How all this works?
in first for loop i traverse through the loop and put all the odd numbers before the even numbers.
But since it doesnt sort them.
in next for loop which has insertion sort. I basically did is only like sorted only odd numbers first in array using if statement. Then when i == odd the nested for loop then doesnt go through all the odd numbers instead it only counts the even numbers and then sorts them.

Comment: what is `index`? Please read [example].

Comment: Can you explain your sorting algorithm?

Comment: @JohnFilleau check now

Comment: @Stef can you check now at the bottom if you can understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you know the complexity of your partitioning (let's say `A`) and sorting algorithms (let's call this one `B`).

You first partition your `n` element array, then sort `m` element, and finally sort `n - m` elements. So the total complexity would be:

```
A(n) + B(m) + B(n - m)
```

Depending on what `A` and `B` actually are you should probably be able to simplify that further.

**Edit:** Btw, unless the goal of your code is to try and implement partitioning/sorting algorithms, I believe this is much clearer:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
void partition_and_sort (T & values) {
  auto isOdd = [](auto const & e) { return e % 2 == 1; };
  auto middle = std::partition(std::begin(values), std::end(values), isOdd);
  std::sort(std::begin(values), middle);
  std::sort(middle, std::end(values));
}
```

Complexity in this case is `O(n) + 2 * O(n * log(n)) = O(n * log(n))`.

**Edit 2:** I wrongly assumed `std::partition` keeps the relative order of elements. That's not the case. Fixed the code example.

Comment: I got your point but what will be complexity of (n-m) I am finding it difficult to find complexity of that part

Comment: @abdullah `(n - m)` is a variable made up of the constant `n` and the variable `m`. It doesn't have complexity, it's just a value. You can find out the min and max values of it in order to determine the best and worst case complexity of your total algorithm

Comment: Complexity is generally used to give you an idea of how long a certain algorithm will take. But the notation hides many things, e.g. constant time. So for example if you want to sort 100 elements, then an `O(n^2)` algorithm might be faster than an `O(n)` one if the `O(n)` one is actually `O(n) + 22 seconds`. So for actual implementations you still need to measure. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity.

Comment: So it will as it is.. Like A(n) + B(m) + B(n-m) they cant be furthur simplified.?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Sorry if it is stupid but if we get complexity like n + m + (n-m). So can we simplify it like ----> n + m + n - m => 2n => n ??????

Comment: @Darhuuk Sorry if it is stupid but if we get complexity like n + m + (n-m). So can we simplify it like ----> n + m + n - m => 2n => n ??????

Comment: There's no such thing as complexity `n`. If the complexity is linear in the number of elements `n`, then it would be `O(n)`. So for the example give give, then you'd get `O(n) + O(m) + O(n - m)`. Now it's been over 15 years since I was thought about this, so I'm a little rusty, but I that would basically be equivalent to `O(n)`, since constants are simplified out. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.